# Is there a way to get the currently logged user’s colleague list using ECMA client script?

Tags: development, javascript, client-object-model

Is there a way to get the currently logged user’s colleague list using ECMA client script?

Used the below script to pull the currently logged user name:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");  
                    var context = null;
                    var web = null;
                    var currentUser = null;
                        function getWebUserData() {
                            context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                            web = context.get_web();
                            currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
                            currentUser.retrieve();
                            context.load(web);
                            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
                        }
                        function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
                            var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
                            alert('User name:' + userObject.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + userObject.get_loginName());
                        }
                        function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
                            alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                        }
                        //getWebUserData();
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with ECMA as it allows only a limited functionalities, HttpHandler would a solution.